# Adding a different value to a list based on number of iteration in a for loop

Tags: python, json, pandas, for-loop, html-parsing

I'm new to Python and programming in general and I am having trouble with a website parsing project.

This is the code I managed to write:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
import json

#necessary lists
url_list = [
    "https://warframe.market/items/melee_riven_mod_(veiled)",
    "https://warframe.market/items/zaw_riven_mod_(veiled)"
    ]
item_list = []
items_name = []
combined_data = []
iteration = 0


#looping for every url found in url_list
for url in url_list:
    #requesting data
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    #splitting the last part of the url which has the name of the item that I want to insert in the dataframe
    name = url.split("/")[4]
    items_name.append(name)

    #Finding in the parsed HTML code where the JSON file starts ( it start from <script> n°2)
    results = soup.find_all('script')[2].text.strip()
    data = json.loads(results)
    combined_data.append(data) #combining all the data into one list


    #filtering only the users who sell the items and are either "ingame" or "online"
    for payload in combined_data[iteration]["payload"]["orders"]:
        if payload["order_type"] == "sell" and (payload["user"]["status"] == "online" or payload["user"]["status"] == "ingame"):
            p = payload
            item_list.append(p) 
            #adding the items names to the item list       ???? PROBLEM ?????
            item_list = [dict(item, **{'name':items_name[iteration]}) for item in item_list]
    #trying to change the list from where the data gets taken from and the items name        ????? PROBLEM ????
    iteration += 1        
    
    #creating a dataframe with all the values
    df = pd.DataFrame(item_list).sort_values(by=["platinum"])
```

What I'm trying to do and can't find a solution to, is to add to item_list the name of the item which the url refers to.

e.g.

| index | platinum | quantity | ... | items name (problematic column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 2 | 11 | 1 | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 3 | 12 | 2 | ... | zaw_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 4 | ... | ... | ... | zaw_riven_mod_(veiled) |

But items name column has the same name for all the rows like this:

| index | platinum | quantity | ... | items name (problematic column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 2 | 11 | 1 | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 3 | 12 | 2 | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |
| 4 | ... | ... | ... | melee_riven_mod_(veiled) |

So I wanted to ask what am I doing wrong in the for loop? It iterates 2 times which is the amount of urls in the `url_list` but it doesn't change the name of the item.
What am I not seeing?

Comment: When I copy your code, it raises an error. Does it have one when you copy and run it directly?

Comment: I can't run your code. If you fix it, I can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I had an indantation problem. It should be fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if payload["order_type"] == "sell" and (payload["user"]["status"] == "online" or payload["user"]["status"] == "ingame"):
     p = payload
     item_list.append(p)
     #adding the items names to the item list       ???? PROBLEM ?????
     item_list = [dict(item, **{'name':items_name[iteration]}) for item in item_list]
```

To this:

```
if payload["order_type"] == "sell" and (payload["user"]["status"] == "online" or payload["user"]["status"] == "ingame"):
    payload['name'] = items_name[iteration]
    item_list.append(payload)
```

Note, that instead of having a separate variable `iteration` and incrementing it, you can loop over `url_list` using `enumerate`, which provides both the item *and* its index at each iteration:

```
for iteration, url in enumerate(url_list):
    ....
```